# C++: Field has incomplete type

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

I am trying to implement the strategy design pattern as an exercise. My classes are pretty simple:

## 1) Fly.cpp

```
class Fly
{
    public:
        Fly();
        bool fly();
};

class CanFly : public Fly
{
    public:
        bool fly()
        {
            return true;
        }
};

class CantFly : public Fly
{
    public:
        bool fly()
        {
            return false;
        }
};
```

## 2) Animal.cpp

```
class Fly;

class Animal
{
    Fly myFly;

public:
    Animal(Fly f);
    void setFly(Fly f);
    Fly getFly();
};

Animal::Animal(Fly f)
{
    myFly = f;
}

void Animal::setFly(Fly f)
{
    myFly = f;
}

Fly Animal::getFly()
{
    return myFly;
}
```

## 3) Dog.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal;

class Dog : public Animal
{
    public:
        Dog(Fly f);
};

Dog::Dog(Fly f)
{
    setFly(f);
    cout << "Dog : " << getFly().fly() << endl;
}
```

## 4) Bird.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal;

class Bird : public Animal
{
    public:
        Bird(Fly f);
};

Bird::Bird(Fly f)
{
    setFly(f);
    cout << "Bird : " << getFly().fly() << endl;
}
```

## 5) AnimalTest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Dog;
class Bird;
class CanFly;
class CantFly;

int main()
{
    Fly f1 = new CanFly();
    Fly f2 = new CantFly();

    Bird b(f1);
    Dog d(f2);

    return 0;
}
```

The error which I get upon building the code is :

```
Animal.cpp:5:6: error: field 'myFly' has incomplete type 'Fly'
  Fly myFly;
      ^
```

Can anyone help me why?

Thanks

Comment: do you know what an abstract class is?

Comment: It should be cannot not "cant". Read up about the keyword  `virtual`

Comment: You need a body for the `fly` constructor

Comment: ... And read up about references and `const`

Give you something to do :-)

Comment: Please read elementary introduction to programming.

Comment: @Walter Yep, trying to do just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incomplete type error means that compiler doesn't see definition of the class, only declaration.
If you create an object or if you pass an object by value then you need to provide a definition of the class to the compiler. You do create objects and pass them around by values hence you need to include definition of relevant classes you pass into cpp files.

**But that is not what you really want to do.**
Your intention is to employ polymorphism so you need to pass objects by reference or by pointer instead.

Your Animal class should be:

```
class Animal
{
    Fly &myFly;

public:
    Animal(Fly &f);
    void setFly(Fly &f);
    Fly const &getFly();
};
```

That way you can pass any of Fly, CanFly, or CantFly objects into Animal object.

You also need to reorganise your code. You need to separate class definitions into header files. For example:

```
//Animal.h
class Fly; <=== Declaration. OK here.
class Animal
{
    Fly &myFly;

public:
    Animal(Fly &f);
    void setFly(Fly &f);
    Fly const &getFly();
};
```

Then you need to  include headers into cpp. Example:

```
#include "Animal.h"
class Dog : public Animal <=== Compiler needs definition of Animal here
{
    public:
        Dog(Fly f);
};
```

Note the difference between following definitions:

```
Fly Animal::getFly()
{
    return myFly;
}
```

Returns a copy of object stored in myFly.

```
Fly const &Animal::getFly()
{
    return myFly;
}
```

Returns a constant reference to an object myFly

Also, perhaps, you do not need `Fly, CanFly, CantFly` classes at all. Classes `Bird, Dog` already "know" if they can or cannot fly. Sure, you are doing an exercise but still Fly, CanFly, etc seem to be redundant and artificial here.

Comment: +1, but perhaps you should explain _why_ they should pass by reference or pointer in this case (polymorphism) because that is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a `class`, its *definition* is required. A statement like

```
class Fly;
```

is not a definition, but merely a *declaration*. A class that has been declared cannot be used, but you can define pointers and references to such a class.

So, to get your code working, you should split the code into header files (.hpp) containing the class definitions and source files (.cpp) containing the (non-inline) definitions of any class members declared in the headers.

Moreover, you seem to want to use polymorphism, but *forgot* to declare the member `bool Fly::fly()` to be `virtual`. I think what you want is

```
// file Fly.hpp
struct Fly
{
  virtual bool fly() const = 0;
};

struct CanFly : Fly
{
  bool fly()
  { return true; }
};

struct CantFly : Fly
{
  bool fly()
  { return false; }
};
```

and then

```
// file Animal.hpp
struct Fly;                  // forward declaration
struct Animal
{
  const Fly*const myFly;      // use pointer to forwardly declared class
                              // const data member is public (serves as getter)
  bool fly() const;
protected:
  Animal(Fly const&f);
  // no setter: an Animal cannot change its flying behaviour
};
```

and

```
// file Animal.cpp
#include "Fly.hpp"
#include "Animal.hpp"

Animal::Animal(Fly const&f)
: myFly(&f) {}

bool Animal::fly() const
{ return myFly->fly(); }       // polymorphic call
```

However, I don't like this pattern. The problem is that in order to define a `Bird` or a `Dog` as derived from `Animal`, you need to provide a reference to an actual `CanFly` and `CantFly`, respectively, to the constructor of their base `Animal`. Moreover, there is nothing that qualifies an `Animal` other than whether it can fly or not, so why have this class `Animal` (in addition to `Fly`)?

Comment: I think `bool Fly` for an object called `Fly` might also be a problem

Comment: If you want `Fly` to behave polymorphically you can't take it by value that will just slice it.

Comment: @EdHeal ?? where is(was) there `bool Fly`?

Comment: ... Sorry - one is in capitals the other is not. Anyway a silly name for a method just to rely on capitalisation

Comment: @EdHeal *silly name for a method just to rely on capitalisation* This is a common method and I merely copied it from the OP.

Comment: Walter - I is stupid to reply on capitalization (or pluralization for that matter). It can lead to errors that can be avoided. I know you are just copying the OP but most coding standards frown on this behaviour

Answer (score -2):

change your `fly.cpp` to `fly.h`, in `Animal.cpp` you should `#include<fly.h>` Or just define your `myFly` as a pointer `Fly* myFly`.

Comment: This does not explain the problem.

Comment: @Walter His file hierarchy is poor. Without `#include<fly.h>` in `Animal.cpp`, the compiler can not find the definition of  `class Fly`. So it will warn that it is an incomplete class. Just define the field as a pointer, then it's definition is not needed by the compiler.

Comment: @Shindou - That may be the case but your answer does not answer the problem